# Select discontinuous range based on column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in columns A:I. The data in column A will always go through to the last row, but other rows in other columns will sometimes be blank. How do I select the range based on the last row in column A? For example, sometimes column A will have 40 rows of data but column I will be blank after row 3. I would still want to select A1:I40.

Ultimately, I want to use VBA to format and put a filter on this range, so I am hoping to not include any blank rows after the last used row in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:I" & N).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: also `Range("I1",Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))` is possible here ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked! I tried it a bunch of times and it wasn't working and then I realized I had some garbage earlier in the macro that was making it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Gary's Student gave you the answer

maybe you're interested in expanding the feature and want to consider the last row with at least one non blank cell in the whole columns range (columns "A:I" in your example), irrespective of which column has it, than you could use:

```
Function LastRow(sht As Worksheet, columnsStrng As String) As Long
    With sht
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .columns(columnsStrng)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            LastRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

and here follows an example of how to use it

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("mysheet1")
    ws.columns("A:I").Resize(LastRow(ws, "A:I")).Select
End Sub
```

This assumes your data are constants (i.e. actual cells content is not a "formula").
But it can be easily enhanced to consider "formula" data as well

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to use Gary's Student's reply successfully!